# Microsoft word crashes when deactive by input method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, input-method-kit

I am developping an input method. Now I have a crash on microsoft word.
When the current edit field is deactive, i need to do some job to clean the marked text. I use:

```
-(void) deactivateServer:(id) sender
{
     ......
     [sender setMarkedText:@"" selectionRange:NSMakeRange(0,0) replacementRange:NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, NSNotFound)];
}
```

but when I do it in word, it has a crash for this "setMarkedText". It likes word has does some job to clean the mared text itself.
Does anyone have some idea? Thank you.